# Sending binary SMS using different phones

Tags: java-me, midlet, pdu

I have midlet application which sends binary SMSes. Part of code responsible for sending SMS (copied from some tutorial):

```
    MessageConnection smsConnection =
            (MessageConnection)Connector.open(destAddress);

    //Create binary message
    BinaryMessage binaryMSG = (BinaryMessage)smsConnection.newMessage(
            MessageConnection.BINARY_MESSAGE);

    //Setting destination add
    binaryMSG.setAddress(destAddress);

    //Add payload data
    binaryMSG.setPayloadData(data);

    //Now send the message
    smsConnection.send(binaryMSG);
    smsConnection.close();
```

i've tested it on nokia e51, e52 and 3120c phones and everything seemed ok. then i checked recieved data. data recievied from e52 and 3120c phones was ok but data from e51 was corrupted. some bytes values were chcanged to 0x1a value. all these changed bytes had value between 0x83 and 0x9e. doeas anyone know what is the reason for that?

Edit: I want to see SMS PDU before SMSC puts hand on it, is there possibility to see PDU of SMS i'm sending? MessageConnection class and Message interface seems to have rather poor functionality.